# PHP/HTML/CSS: Styling an array of data

Tags: php, html, css, arrays, layout

When importing an array of data from a database (i'm using php/mysql), how do I go about styling this information with css? I'm assuming I add html tags to each separate piece of data from the array? but if so at which stage would I assign these tags?

I'm a bit new to php but am ok with css and xhtml.

At the moment my array contains:

```
Business_Name  |  Address  |  Tel | Service  | Url | Email | Recommendations | Image_Url
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: A picture paints a thousand words :0)

[image: Listings]

Comment: add the css and html on output, can't know exactly what css\html as you have not told us what you want it to look like on screen.

Comment: I think his questions is actually more basic than that... are you asking 'how to loop this array and display it?'...

Comment: Are these items going into a form, so that the data can be edited for example?

Comment: @brian no just looking to add style to the echoed result of my query.

Comment: @cups the data will not be going into a form and will be uneditable to anyone other than myself. It will appear as a business listing on my site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try doing a for loop width you array

something like

```
<?php
  echo "<ul>";
 foreach($array as $arrkey){
     echo "<li>".$arrkey."</li>";   

 }
 echo "</ul>";
?>
```

and do some css on the `<li>`.

edit:

```
 <?php

   $cont=0;

      echo '<ul>';
     foreach($array as $arrkey){
         echo '<li class="yourclass-.$cont.'">'.$arrkey.'</li>';   
        $cont++;
     }
     echo "</ul>";
    ?>
```

then style each `<li>`

like

```
li.yourclass-0{

}
```

Comment: Just to point out - $arrkey is /actually/ that array element's value. A better variable name might be $arrval.

Comment: Yes $arrkey is the value of the array elements.

Comment: What would happen if each list item was to be styled differently? Where could I add a class or id?

Comment: If you're planning on giving each element in your array the same style, use the technique listed in this post. If you want to use different styles for each element in the array, you're much better off using an associative array and listing out the elements and their classes individually. For instance, `<span class="business-name"><?php echo $the_array["business_name"]; ?></span> <span class="address"><?php echo $the_array["address"]; ?></span>` etc...

Comment: but you can also try making the $arrkey as a class.

Comment: @rrapuya Could you explain $cont (or should it be $count) for me please? I notice you have concatenated it with the class name. Does this add an auto increment to each list item?

Comment: $cont is a variable name. Concatenating it with the class name will make the unique class for each li. making li.yourclass-0,li.yourclass-1 and so on..

Comment: Ah ok thank you. So what causes the variable to increase by a value of 1 each time? is it the ++ ?

Answer (score 1):

This is quite an open ended question, but I'll endeavour to give you some general pointers.

There are a few options open to you. The easiest and most straightforward is to just start spitting out HTML from your PHP script, like so:

`<table><tr><td><?php echo $arr['Business_Name']; ?></td>...<td><img src="<?php echo $arr['Image_Url']; ?>"></td></tr></table>`

In short, `echo` is your friend.

That's not always the best option though - if you have anything more than a very simple script, this kind of approach can get very messy and hard to follow very quickly. Your beautifully formatted PHP get all gummed up with HTML, and it's not pretty, and becomes hard to maintain.

What you want to do in this case is separate your concerns - keep "display" logic separate from "business" logic.

This can be done in a few different ways - I suggest you look at some templating tools like Smarty or some frameworks such as Zend - these go a long way towards separating business logic from display logic.

Comment: Thanks for your input alex. I really would like to avoid anything messy. I will have a look into templating tools.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are inquiring only about "designing" the output. If so, the question become more vague.

Designing depends on how you wish to show these data to your viewers. If you want a tabular structure, use `<table>`. Or if they are to be shown as a list, use `<ul>` or `<ol>` and use CSS to style it. Adding style properties inline is a very bad approach. Avoid that.

Like Alex said, this question is very open ended and vague. Try refining your question a little more.

Answer (score 0):

if we suppose $res is your result set then ,

$str = "table width='100%'";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
     $str .= "tr
                td class='class_name'".$row['col_name']." /td
              /tr";
}

$str .= "/table";

echo $str;