# Images placed within responsive circles

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

## The Problem

I am trying to place images within a responsive circle (div), which is itself the child of another responsive circle.

I feel I have the divs nailed, but as soon as I include an image the proportions get distorted and I can't figure out the correct CSS code.

The two divs are for a future border effect I am planning.

## What I currently have...

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/samholguin/pen/InFwk)

HTML

```
<section class="col-4">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="outta-circle">  
      <div class="circle">
        <!-- <img src="#"> -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">         
    <div class="outta-circle">  
      <div class="circle">
        <!-- <img src="#"> -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.col-4 {
  width: 1068px;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 48.68%;
    max-height: 520px;
    background-color: white;
}

.outta-circle {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  margin: 80px auto;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: red;
}

.circle {
    width: 96.15%;
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 96.15%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

The solution to my issue is to use the CSS Background property for the class `.circle` (see comments, cheers for the help there!!).

I have a number of news stories each with their own image placed in a PHP array - I plan to use a database but for the time being an array will suffice - therefore the `img src` will change depending on which news story is loaded.

I was going to use:

```
<img src="<?php echo $article["img"]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $article["title"]; ?>">
```

Now I have to use the CSS Background property, how would I parse the PHP into the HTML/CSS??

I'm new to this, apologies if I haven't been clear...

Comment: I can't understand exactly what you're trying to achieve. Are you looking for something like this? http://codepen.io/nobitagit/full/trEuJ

Comment: Are you just trying to create a circular image to put in the `div`? If so look [here](http://bavotasan.com/2011/circular-images-with-css3/)

Comment: @Zeaklous Thank you very much, that is what I'm after, however I wasn't clear on my end goal. Please see the edit above after my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you can make your images a basic circle I said by following [this tutorial](http://bavotasan.com/2011/circular-images-with-css3/)

```
.circular {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 150px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 150px;
    -moz-border-radius: 150px;
    background: url(http://link-to-your/image.jpg) no-repeat;
    }
```

But for your use, make a foreach loop in your PHP [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504101/php-html-css-styling-an-array-of-data) to be able to apply CSS directly to it (given the images in the array are stored like `<img src="www.mysrc.com/kittens.jpg" />`. If they are just the URL you have to change the echo line in the foreach loop a little)

```
<?php

   $cont=0;
   echo '<ul>';
   foreach($array as $arrval){
       echo '<li class="circular">'.$arrval.'</li>';   
       $cont++;
   }
   echo "</ul>";
   ?>
```

And then you can apply the CSS with

```
li.circular{
        width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 150px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 150px;
    -moz-border-radius: 150px;
}
```

**Edit** based on my chat with you. Set up the PHP this way first (has to be outside of `<script>` tags)

```
<?php
$array1 = array('img' => "http://izview.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2008/07/the-chandelier.jpg",
               'title' => 'article',
               'content' => 'This is the content coming from PHP',
               'date' => "6/27/2013");
?>
```

And call it by converting it to json and putting it in `<script>` tags to be applied to the element.

**Javascript fix** (no PHP) [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/YW2QG/2/)

```
var articleArray = [{img: "http://izview.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2008/07/the-chandelier.jpg", title: "Article Name", content: "This is the content coming from PHP", date: "6/27/2013"},
    {}
];
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess my main issue is getting this all to work responsively with my border effect....with images of differing aspect ratios :) [link](http://www.universalphysique.co.uk/responsive-image-wrapper-test.html) This is what I'd like to do for each news story that has a different image url.

Comment: would using 'background-image:url('<?php echo $url ?>');' work if i included it in the foreach loop?

Comment: I don't understand what the aspect ratios of the images have to do with calling an image from a PHP array... And no, you would have to have `echo 'background-image:url("'.$arrval.'");'` in the PHP foreach loop.

Answer (score 2):

So if you're trying to achieve a sort of 3d effect on a rounded image you can definitely get it with just the image tag only so the code will be very clean and it will be easy to place the image through PHP.

Simply assign a 100% border-radius and a proper box-shadow to the image, something along these lines:

```
 img {
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 9px 0 red;
 }
```

Take a look at this http://codepen.io/nobitagit/pen/trEuJ

As the code is this simple it will be very easy to make it responsive-friendly as to your needs.

Comment: the images I have differ in their aspect ratio and my desired border effect differs dramatically from my CodePen. Again this is my error in not explaining my full intentions.

Comment: Please refer to this link for something similar to my end result [link]http://www.universalphysique.co.uk/responsive-image-wrapper-test.html ignoring the text placement etc... :) and the mess when the window is resized (no media queries yet). I'm sure I'll look back at this code in horror once I'm more experienced but for now it seems to work. I just need a way of changing the Background 'url' on the fly as the articles change. Any help would be great!!!

Answer (score 1):

@Zeaklous I have tried your method, but I believe in this instance I have to use CSS `Background-Image: url();`

Therefore I need a method of dynamically changing the `Background-Image: url();` and after a little searching it seems following [this](http://css-tricks.com/css-variables-with-php/) technique using `background-image:url('<?php echo $url ?>');` would work?!?

It's a stab in the dark though, my 1st time with code of this nature.

Comment: If you have a number variable (in this case called ID) with a numerical value associated with each article you could use something like `<img style="background-image:url(" + <?php echo $array[ID]?> + ")" />`

Comment: @Zeaklous this is my sorry attempt using your method when trying to make it responsive [link](http://www.universalphysique.co.uk/responsive-image-wrapper-test.html), I now have a working example of what I am after, although I'm sure semantically it is a mess so your opinion would be great.... [working example](http://www.universalphysique.co.uk/), this seems to be responsive

Comment: Maybe with my current code and your above comment this will be an acceptable fix?